# What's a good plugin or guide I can use to create javascript widgets from a Rails App?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, widget

I've been looking around for a while now and the best guide I've seen so far is Dr Nic's DIY widgets how to [(here)](http://drnicwilliams.com/2006/11/21/diy-widgets).

I haven't been able to make something like this work:

Assuming this is my widget code:

```
<script src="http://mysite/nomnoms.js"> </script>
```

And my nomnoms controller looks like (assume that the list partial exists and simply lists down a link to the show page of each nomnom in the @nomnoms variable):

```
class NomnomsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @nomnoms = Nomnom.find(:all)
  @content = render_to_string(:partial => 'list')
end

end
```

And in the index.js of my nomnoms_controller I have:

```
page << "document.write('<div>'"
page << "document.write('#{@content.to_json}')"
page << "</div>"
```

The above setup doesn't render anything :(. But when I change the second line of index.js to:

```
page << "document.write('nomnoms should be here')
```

...the widget renders the text. Any help or even a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I was able to make the divs render after doing two things:

First, I instantiated the string in a variable inside index.js like so:

```
text = @content.to_json.chop.slice(1..-1)
```

And used that as the replacement in the actual javascript.

```
page << %Q{document.getElementById("nomnom-list").innerHTML="#{text}"}
```

Second, as you can see in the first code snippet, I removed both leading and trailing unescaped double quotes from the string.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does index.js render the divs?
2. If you enter http://mysite/nomnoms.js in your browser, does it render the script?

George